# Same file needed for multiple packages in GoLang

Tags: go, testify, go-testing

I am using this method [here](https://www.cyphar.com/blog/post/20170412-golang-integration-coverage) to collect the code coverage for my system tests. The overall idea is that I need a dummy test so that I can generate an executable that calls the `main()` in the package. As a result, I have a file like the following in each and every packages:

TestRunner.go:

```
//go:build testrunner

package main

import "testing"

import (
    "os"
)

func TestRunMain(t *testing.T) {
    main()
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // This is where I parse flags
    m.Run()
}
```

As shown, it is a really simple file but I would need a duplicate of this for each package to generate the executables since they all have their own `main()`. From the maintainability point of view, this does not seem to be the best practice as if I were to change the flag parsing in the test runner, I would have to make the same change across all packages.

One way I can think of is to keep a template. Then write a script in the Makefile so that every time I build the project, it copy-pastes the template to each package and after it generates the executables, the copies will get deleted. But this feels rather cumbersome.

Is there any other way I can keep only one copy of the file and somehow have it reference the `main()`s from different packages?

Comment: You can use one file with symbolic links to wherever other copies must be

Comment: @BurakSerdar Could you elaborate or give an example?

Comment: Create one file in a directory, maybe `shared/main.g`, then add a symbolic link to that under each package that needs it

Comment: @BurakSerdar I kept thinking it should be something with Go... that does seem to be the cleanest. Thank you!